# Topology 'dents'

Tags: modeling, topology

When modelling I always run into this strange problem where the quad bends, creating some sort of dent. I do low-poly modelling so I move the corners of the quad quite a lot. I also use proportionate editing frequently for some occasional tweaking.

[image: Example Image]

How do I avoid these dents? Should I try a different technique?

Thanks

Comment: what do you call "dents", are you talking about the fact that your face is concave? You have no choice, a face is made of 2 tris and when it's not flat it will bend along a line that goes from a vertex to the opposite

Comment: Hi :). It's called [*non-planar polygon*](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/MayaLT-Modeling/files/GUID-3868CB96-3A61-4F14-8A61-EB250A125E96-htm.html). Don't know if there are any automatic tools to prevent it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll read more about this.